# How to crop the specific selected image in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

Unfortunately, there is not possibility to crop the image inside the multiple selection of the photoshop. May I ask please how to crop the selected image as shown in the attached example?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change just *one* of those images and **not** actually remove anything else? You may merely need a layer mask and *no actual cropping*. (Photoshop does not "crop" individual layers)

Comment: @Scott, thanks. Yes, I would like to crop the selected image. To make it equal to the other two demo images.  Does Layer Mask helps to create the similar image?

Comment: Well, you seemed to have chosen a correct answer. So, I assume you got things working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Photoshop selections are indicated by marching ants. Those shown in your screenshot are merely the transform handles which appear when a layer is selected and the Move Tool is selected.

Instead, to get a selection <kbd>Ctrl / Command</kbd>+click the layer thumbnail in the layers panel.

To crop it, do *Image > Crop*

Comment: thank you for the explanation. Today I learned about the difference between selection and Move Tool. I am expecting to stretch the selected image to make it equal size with other two images.

Comment: @Python - stretching an image has nothing to do with cropping it.  Sounds like you have some other problem you haven't mentioned. Are you having problems stretching an image?

Comment: yes. After cropping, I would like to make the cropped image similar size of another two images.

Answer (score 0):

Select the part you want to preserve with a selection tool, and in the layer panel, click on the fusion mask.

Not really a "crop", but you can then separate the layer from his mask (by clicking the chain between the two in layer panel) and transform it (then click between mask and layer to reactivate the chain)